# How to return blob item from localForage in service worker?

Tags: blob, service-worker, indexeddb, localforage

in my service worker i store mp4 video in indexedDB with localforage library in a blob data. It's work ! but i don't know how can i return this blob data.

This is my fetchHandler code :

```
const fetchHandler = async (event) => {
    const getResponse = async () => {
        const request = event.request;
        if( request.destination === 'video' ){
            // Get from indexedDB
            const value = await localforage.getItem('video');
            // How return the video from indexedDB cache ?
            if( value ) return value; // not working
            // Add in indexedDB
            var networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
            localforage.setItem('video', networkResponse.blob() ).then(function (value) {
                // Do other things once the value has been saved.
                console.log(value);
            }).catch(function(err) {
                // This code runs if there were any errors
                console.log(err);
            });
        }else{
            const openedCache = await caches.open(SW_CACHE_NAME);
            const cacheResponse = await openedCache.match(request);
            if (cacheResponse) return cacheResponse;

            var networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
            const cachePutResponse = await openedCache.put(request, networkResponse.clone());
            if (cachePutResponse) return cachePutResponse;
        }

        return networkResponse;
    };
    event.respondWith(getResponse());
};
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a valid `Response` object to `event.respondWith()`. That entails a response body (which is what you get back from `localforeage.getItem()`), but also some response headers.

You can use the [`Response` constructor](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#response-class) to create that, and return it from your `getResponse()` function.

The code could look something like:

```js
const value = await localforage.getItem('video');
if (value) {
  // See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit for what's accepted
  // as a BodyInit.
  return new Response(value, {
    headers: {
      // Replace this with the actual MIME type for the video.
      'content-type': 'video/mp4',
      // Include any other headers here if desired.
    }
  });
}
```